# Runge's Approximation Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation-theory

This is a homework problem, so my apologies for a seeming lack of motivation. I want to understand what's going on in this problem more than I want someone to just write down the solution, so if someone could spell out for me the underpinnings of what I'm missing, that'd be best.

1) Consider the region defined by $\Omega = \{ z \in \mathbb C: 1< |z| < 2$ or $4 < |z| < 5 \}$. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\Omega$, and $K$ be compactly contained in $\Omega$. Show that there is a function $g$ holomorphic everywhere but $0$ and $3$ so that $\sup_K |f - g | < 1/2$.

This part of the problem I was able to do using Runge's theorem. Staring at the location of the points, and the region in question, we see that it contains a point in each bounded region of the complement of $\Omega$, so we can come up with a sequence of rational functions with poles at $0$ and $3$ which uniformly approximate $f$. Then we just choose a member of this sequence so that the approximation is sufficiently close.

The next part of the problem is what I find challenging.

2)Now redefine $K = \{ z \in \mathbb C: 4/3 \leq |z| \leq 3/2$ or $41/10 \leq |z| \leq 45/10 \}$.

The question is to find a function $f$ which is holomorphic on $\Omega$ so there does NOT exist a holomorphic function $g: \mathbb C - \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb C$ where $\sup_K |f-g| \leq 1$.

Staring at this sub-double-annulus (wow that's a mouthful), it seems hard to know what to do. My intuition says to assume that such a function $g$ does exist, and then try to find some contradiction. One thought I had was to try to integrate $f-g$ over some closed curve, and use the fact that the sup is bounded to estimate the magnitude of the integral. I tried an approach like this with a few functions $f$, looking for things that made the integral kind of simple. In each case, I would run into a problem because no matter how I tried to compute the integrals, I'd end up not knowing enough about $g$ in order to say that the estimate didn't work...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @copper.hat $K$. Let me go check the statement of the problem to make sure I didn't do anything silly. Yep. Definitely $K$. The big difference between part 1 and 2 is that in part 2, the only poles can be at $0$, where in part 1 there can be two poles, one at $0$ but also one at $3$.

Comment: Don't worry about submitting homework problems when you accompany it with such a nice description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $f(z) = c/(z-3),$ with $c$ to be determined. Let $g$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$ Consider

$$\int_{C_2} (f(z)-g(z))\, dz \,- \int_{C_1} (f(z)-g(z))\, dz $$

for well chosen circles $C_1,C_2$ lying in $K.$ If $|c|$ is large, the answer you get above will be incompatible with $|f-g| \le 1$ on $K.$

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, but it appeared that I needed to know more about g than I did, like a residue or something. At least that's what I thought... I was integrating around the boundary of the anulus.

Comment: because we are subtracting integrals, the contribution of g drops out, while the contribution of f doesn't

Comment: Okay. I must have made a mistake then. I'll check my calculations and try again.

Comment: The only way I can think to make the contribution of $g$ drop out is if $g$ is holomorphic within the circle. So this made me think to choose a circle which is contractible in $K$, so it does not contain the origin. But any such circle also does not contain $3$, so $f$ would also be holomorphic there. Can you say a few more words about why subtracting the integrals makes $g$ disappear?

Comment: Let $C_1 = \{|z|=4/3\}, C_2 = \{|z|=41/10\},$ both with the standard positive orientations. Then $\int_{C_1} g = \int_{C_2} g,$ this value being $2\pi i \text { Res }(g,0).$ On the other hand, $\int_{C_1} f = 0, \int_{C_2} f = 2\pi i c.$

Comment: I get $2\pi ic$ equal to the difference in integrals in my answer above. Slap absolute values on to see that if the approximation holds, then $2\pi|c| \le 1\cdot 2\pi (41/10) + 1\cdot 2\pi (4/3).$ So I see that $|c| > 41/10+4/3$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: Oh! I'm so dense. I don't know why on earth I never thought to take one circle from each boundary component. That's not just mathematical obliviousness... it's a whole new level of oblivious. As soon as you wrote down the two different boundary paths it hit me! I was waaaay over-thinking it. I got to the point involving Res $(g,0)$ and it didn't occur to me to try to cancel it with the other loop.